# Crash with 'Could not load NIB in bundle ' while reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I need to expand the `tableviewcell` when the user taps on a particular button(which is like a toggle, tapping will expand the row and taping other time will collapse the row) in that cell. So I have implemented the custom delegate method to know which cell need to get reloaded and reload that particular cell with `'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths'`.

It works fine while tapping the button for first time, and even for the second time, but its getting crashed by the third time saying 'Could not load NIB in bundle: `'NSBundle </Users/path/myApp.app> (loaded)'` with name `'ContactCell''`.

My question is reloading of the cell which works for first time and second time why its crashing for third time?

My Code:

```
[contactTableView beginUpdates];   // Inside the custom delegate method
[contactTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; // indexpath is which i get from cell through custom delegate method
[contactTableView endUpdates];

 ContactTableCell *cell; //Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContactCell";

    cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        // load a new cell from the nib file
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.contactCell;
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.indexPath = indexPath;
        self.contactCell = nil;
    }
```

Why is it crashing?

Comment: What is your nib for this cell? ContactCell or ContactTableCell?

Comment: @Mani ContactCell.xib. Its crashing only at sometimes, not all the times. So, the nib name is not the problem I think.

Comment: your tableview width remains the same?Why can't you increase the width of table view?

Comment: @footyapps27 How come increasing the width of tableView make a difference in this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't use uppercase for the start of variables (i.e. CellIdentifier -> cellIdentfier). Also I don't think you need to load the nib in this method, you need to do it in the `ContactTableCell` class

Comment: You increase the width of there tableview, the table view cell will automatically expand.

Comment: Do you only want to expand a certain selected cell?

Comment: check your xib name ....may be spelling mistake..

Comment: Your problem is the statements after the if condition

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are a couple of problems with this. Firstly, loading from the nib should not be in this class it should be in the `ContactTableCell` class in an `init` method (`initWithNib` or what you want to call it)

Your XIB needs to make sure that `ContactTableCell` is the custom class assigned to it also.

so your init with nib would go something like this

```
//in ContactTableCell.m
-(id)initWithNib{
      self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
      if(self){
         //do extra customisation stuff/ set labels etc.
      }
      return self;
 }
```

Then you would call

```
if (cell == nil) {
    // load a new cell from the nib file
    cell = [[ContactTableCell alloc] initWithNib];
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I'm getting this error ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x110acd30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contactCell.' **

Comment: Where is contactCell defined/initialised and what is its type. Would you be able to edit your post to include the code about contactCell?

Answer (score 0):

Register you nib in `viewDidLoad` once.

```
 NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";

 UINib *nib=[UINib nibWithNibName:cellIdentifier bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 [self.yourTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Hi, I tried with your above code in viewDidLoad but it throws an error with ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x110acd30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contactCell.' **

Comment: Use IB Attribute Inspector to set the cell Identifier(identifier same as added in registerNib method)